# How would I replace this light bulb in the pic

Tags: recessed-lighting, replacement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAXtw.jpg)[image][image]

How would I replace this recessed light with clips?

Comment: Could you zoom out a bit? Could be a bi-pin and you twist like a fluorescent tube, could be a screw in type, or a bi-pin pull out. Might you have a model number/manufacturer label?

Comment: I have added a new picture, not sure if that helps you Jeff

Comment: It looks like the glass is broken. Is it?

Comment: yes I broke glass accidentally while pulling it out

Answer (score 5):

That whole plastic base pulls directly out. That is a compact fluorescent bulb, be careful not to breathe any powder/dust that comes out of the broken tube(s), not good for you.

Comment: I tried pulling the plastic base and it does come out. But I am still unable to remove bulb. Any videos or tricks?

Comment: The base and bulb are a single unit. Post a pic of the removed base

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you pull straight down.

Or it is more likely to be a **gu24 base** that you turn and pull down.

A GU24 base has two pins that you insert into slots and then turn to secure. Usually you have push the bulb into the socket as you turn it, both installing it and taking it out.

It appears that the bulb is broken at the top. ***Where gloves, eye protection and a mask when removing it***.

[GU24 INSTALL YOUTUBE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIiANEstIX4).

[image: adapter with a GU24 base]

*image of an adapter with a GU24 base from amazon.com*

[image: GU24socket]

*Image from Grandbrass.com*